# Android: Format Font in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, linkify

I have two questions

1) Does anyone know, how to apply styles or formatting to alert dialog. I currently use `Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` And use `setMessage()` method to set the content.

2) Also I would like to know how to change the color of the links created by linkify. I don't want the default blue color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Q1. You have to inflate or customize and create a style and apply to AlertDialog

Heres how you inflate a layout and apply it to AlertDialog

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.formatted_dialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
builder.setTitle("Formatted");
builder.setView(view);
```

define all the formatting and styles required in the layout you specified.

You can access specific textview defined in the layout using inflated View i.e.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.formatted_dialog, null);
TextView label=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.i_am_from_formatted_layout_lable);
```

Q2. `android:textColorLink="#FF00FF"` can be used to specify color of link.

**EDIT:**

Sample layout saved as res/layout/link.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="http://www.google.com"
   android:autoLink="web"
   android:textColorLink="#FF00FF"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your onCreate() or where or whenever you want to call AlertDialog

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.link, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Formatted");
builder.setView(view).create().show();
TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

replace `this` with context object if you are calling from some other method.

Comment: I have some doubts. How will the formatted_dialog layout be? Then How should I add my content? And Where should I specify `android:textColorLink` ?

Comment: can you tell me, how to use typeface in AlertDialog

Comment: use findviewid on you custom alert dialog setview and use setTypeface method

Answer (score 3):

you can use following code to change typeface and Text color by extracting TextView from default alertDialog:

```
TextView txtAlertMsg = (TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
txtAlertMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Hi Anand, I tried as said by you but I can't figure out that where I am doing wrong. I got NullPointerException at Gravity set....My Code is Look like as below:                                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setIcon(0);
builder.setTitle("My Title");
builder.setMessage(msg);
builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
((TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
((TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);