# Android AlertDialog title font

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to change the font of `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`title text.

**METHOD 1 :**

```
   TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title); //returns null
```

**METHOD 2 :**

```
   final int titleId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
   TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(titleId); //Also returns null.
```

Is there any other way to get the title `TextView`?

Please note I do not want to use a custom layout.

Thanks.

Comment: Your context is null i think. Check it! Post full code for AlertDialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to work using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741161/1129612)  :

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);  

    Typeface tf = //get the typeface.
    CustomTFSpan tfSpan = new CustomTFSpan(tf);
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(title);
    spannableString.setSpan(tfSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    alertBuilder.setTitle(spannableString);

    AlertDialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

**CustomTFSpan**

```
public class CustomTFSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

  private Typeface typeface;

  public CustomTFSpan(Typeface typeface) {
    super("");
    this.typeface = typeface;
  }

  @Override
  public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyTypeFace(ds, typeface);
  }

  @Override
  public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyTypeFace(paint, typeface);
  }

  private static void applyTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this one

```
TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
```

Without any custom title :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already answer here : [Change Title Font Of Alert Dialog Box Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913956/change-title-font-of-alert-dialog-box-android)

You can simply use a textview and set it as custom title like this : `builder.setCustomTitle(tv2);`

Comment: I have seen his solution. It is similar to using custom layout. Is there a way to get the default title TextView?

Comment: I don't think so there is any way to get the default one but what is the problem in this solution. You can set title from this and also you can change fonts. You can also try some third party dialogue library, may be this is the last option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple TextView

```
TextView tv;
```

And replace

```
builder.setTitle("My Title");
```

with

```
builder.setCustomTitle(tv);
```

Comment: Will it not throw Null poiner exception?

Comment: The above textview (tv) is your widget. So you need to find it using findViewById() method before using it.